# Extracting font colour in Excel formulae

Tags: excel, fonts, colors

I'm designing a poker training app and just adding some finishing touches -

[image: Screenshot]

It may be more of a VBA issue but, I have a column for every card value (all cards from 2 to A in each suit), with the diamonds and hearts coloured in red).

What I would ideally want is for the cards shown in the Hand and Flop columns - to be displayed in red - that is, any pair of characters where the last character in the sequence is either ♥ or ♦

For reference the formula for the 'Hand' column is:

```
=F2&"  "&F3
```

and for the 'Flop' column:

```
=F4&"  "&F5&"  "&F6
```

I've tried conditional formatting, but that highlights the entire cell, rather than just specific characters - and I've tried the following VBA code that froze my excel every time I tried to run it:

```
Function GetColorText(pRange As Range) As String
'Updateby20141105
Dim xOut As String
Dim xValue As String
Dim i As Long
xValue = pRange.Text

For i = 1 To VBA.Len(xValue)

    If pRange.Characters(i, 1).Font.Color = vbRed Then
        xOut = xOut & VBA.Mid(xValue, i, 1)
    End If

Next

GetColorText = xOut
   End Function
```

[Result from below answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Tq2d.png)

Comment: What have you researched / tried so far? Have you tried Conditional Formatting?

Comment: Yes which worked if I wanted to highlight the whole cell, but I'm looking to highlight just certain characters in the cell and leave the rest blank - I also came across a VBA script that did not work-

Comment: Edit your question to include the code you tried, and what the error was.

Comment: ok done - I've added the code at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Public Enum Suits
    spade = 9824
    heart = 9829
    diamond = 9830
    club = 9827
End Enum

Sub ColorSuits(ByRef c As Range)
    Dim s() As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim x As Integer, y As Integer

    s = Split(c.Value, "  ")
    For i = LBound(s) To UBound(s)
          x = InStr(c.Value, s(i))
          y = Len(s(i))
          c.Characters(x, y).Font.Color = SuitColor(s(i))
    Next i
End Sub

Function SuitColor(ByVal s As String)
    Select Case Right(s, 1)
        Case ChrW(heart), ChrW(diamond)
            SuitColor = vbRed
        Case Else
            SuitColor = vbBlack
    End Select
End Function


Sub Test()
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Selection
        ColorSuits c
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: Tried this - it seems to pick up the symbols correctly, using the first symbol found in the cell but then highlight the whole cell in red instead of just the hearts and diamonds - screenshot in question edit